# How to automate the AWS MSK Topics Creation Without using EC2 Instance

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

We've set up the MSK Cluster, VPC, and Security Group in AWS. We want to create an AWS MSK topics without using EC2 instance.
Is it possible to automate this? or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use lambda, ECS / EKS instead of "EC2"

But to create a topic, you only need AdminClient permission directly to the broker, so open external VPC access to MSK, and you can run topic creation scripts wherever. Most Kafka client libraries have methods to create topics, but you'll need to deploy this code somewhere, and it'll eventually end up on machines that might run as some EC2 instance